# Error when grabbing rows within current month

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to grab all rows that fall into the current month. For now, I'm just hard coding the month since I can't even get that to work properly.

I did the following to convert my dates to the format "DD-MON-YYYY'

```
SELECT "MOLECULE_NAME", to_date("FLASK_START_DATE", 'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM EXCEL_SCHEDULE_IMPORT
```

Which gives me the correct date output I want. But now, when I try to grab all the dates that fall into this current month with the following code, it's a no go. Getting the error **"invalid number"**.

```
SELECT "MOLECULE_NAME", to_date("FLASK_START_DATE", 'MM/DD/YYYY')
FROM EXCEL_SCHEDULE_IMPORT
WHERE to_char("FLASK_START_DATE",'Mon-YYYY')='JUN-2017';
```

Any help would be appreciated. I want to end up grabbing all values from a current month based off the system clock. So if you can do that... That would be cool.

**EDIT**: Turns out some of the dates in the date column turn out to have incorrect data, such as "Molecule" or "Sequence". So words instead of a date. Is there any way to ignore those values?

Comment: A better approach is to create a date variable that is a 1st of the current month.  Create another one for the 1st of the following month.  Oracle has an add_months function for this.  filter on `>= the first variable and < the second`.

Comment: What is the datatype of flask_start_date?

Comment: It turns out that the reason I can't convert some of the dates is because someone input some data incorrectly into the server. So some of the Date objects aren't dates, and instead a string like "hello" or "molecule". Is there a way to ignore those values?

Answer (score 0):

If you want data from the current month, why not just do:

```
WHERE "FLASK_START_DATE" like TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'MM') || '/%/' + TO_CHAR(sydate, 'YYYY')
```

Or:

```
WHERE "FLASK_START_DATE" like '06/%/2017'
```

Why go back and forth on string and date conversions?  Also, you should be storing date in the proper data type -- called `DATE`.